# Create an array of a certain type and reuse it

Tags: go

I'm having trouble creating the payload for my graphql resolver. How could I rewrite this to return a completed array?

I'm stuck inside of `c.OnHTML("article", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {}` and can't return the data outside of it.

```golang
type Article struct {
    Title     string `bson:"title"`
    Source    string `bson:"source"`
    Url       string `bson:"url"`
    Timestamp string `bson:"timestamp"`
}
```

```golang
func (r *RootResolver) News() ([]models.Article, error) {

    c := colly.NewCollector(
        colly.MaxDepth(2),
        colly.Async(),
    )

    c.Limit(&colly.LimitRule{Parallelism: 10})

    articles := []models.Article{}

    c.OnHTML("article", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        articleModel := []models.Article{
            {
                Title:     e.ChildText("h3 a"),
                Source:    e.ChildText("a[data-n-tid]"),
                Timestamp: e.ChildAttr("div:last-child time", "datetime"),
                Url:       e.ChildAttr("a[href]", "href"),
            },
        }

        fmt.Println(articleModel)
    })

    c.Visit(SOMEURLHERE)
    c.Wait()

    return articles, nil
}
```

Comment: How `articleModel` data append to `articles` slice inside your `c.OnHTML` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get full list of articles, you need to append new article into `articles` slice inside of your `c.OnHTML` function instead creating new slice.

and return `articles` slice end of the `News()` Method.

```
    articles = append(articles, models.Article{
        Title:     e.ChildText("h3 a"),
        Source:    e.ChildText("a[data-n-tid]"),
        Timestamp: e.ChildAttr("div:last-child time", "datetime"),
        Url:       e.ChildAttr("a[href]", "href"),
    })
```

In your current implementation, `articles := []models.Article{}` creates an empty slice of `models.Article` type. And inside `c.OnHTML`, you creating another slice of `models.Article` type named `articleModel` with and element. That two slices has no any connection. So you need to append new element to your `articles` slice and return it with articles.